# Mediation analysis with interactions and an ordinal mediator produced by mixed level modeling

Tags: mixed-model, survival, mediation, ordered-logit, multinomial-logit

I have two models that have fairly good support, to wit:

A clustered AFT model where time is right-censored (trial failure), regressed off genotype, age, and day of trial, clustered by specific animal. Variable of interest is slope of response (time/days).

A mixed-level model where response also regresses off genotype, age, and day of trial, clustered by specific animal. Response is a "strategy", which can be considered multinomial or ordinal (technically ordinal but some controversy over ordering).

The overall response would be time and the mediator would be strategy. I am presuming partial mediation.

How would I do this in R, for example?